# Windows server: inheritance not applied after folder move

Tags: network-share, access-control-list

I read a lot about strange and unexpected behavior about acl inheritance when folders are moved inside the same volume.
I have a problem similar to this one:
[microsoft-move-file-acl-problem](http://marco-difeo.de/2014/07/07/microsoft-move-file-acl-problem/)

In my case only a user is affected and any effort to reproduce the problem with another user on other folders with similar acls was vain.

My setup:

Windows server 2016 with shared folders

Windows 10 client accessing the folders

**\myserver\myshare\bossfolder\restricted** has limited access and only the boss has full control 
**\myserver\myshare\bossfolder\toProcess** has limited access to the boss (full control) and another windows group

When the boss moves folders with files from **restricted** to **toProcess** these folders don't inherit the acl from **toProcess**, so the users in the group cannot work there.
This behavior is the same described in the linked post but it is almost 5 years old and I'm very surprised it is not solved.
Besides, as stated above, any effort to reproduce the problem with other users on other folders (setting the acl accordingly) was useless.
It seems I'm missing something...

Comment: This [older KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310316/how-permissions-are-handled-when-you-copy-and-move-files-and-folders) article seems to indicate that you can control that behavior in a client by setting the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MoveSecurityAttributes` registry setting

Comment: in the article I linked above of Marco DiFreo he explicitly states that this problem is not solved by **MoveSecurityAttributes**. Besides that registry key was not changed in the *boss* computer so it should be the same on all other clients.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When you move a file to a different folder on the same volume, the file retains it's original permissions. What you're describing is the expected behavior.

Comment: @joeqwerty May be the behavior is by design but according to all people complaining about that it is not what user expects.As stated I had some difficulties in reproducing it so there are some other factors to take into account. Anyway I desperately need a way to make those moved folder inherit the permissions from the new parent folder. Any idea ? Forcing a copy solves the problem and it is a temporary workaround but it is not the solution.

Comment: I would like to ad that Microsoft documentation is somewhat contradictory on this topic. For example in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320246/inherited-permissions-are-not-automatically-updated-when-you-move-fold it is stated that **This behavior cannot be caused by moving a folder when you are running a Windows Vista based computer**

Answer (score 1):

After investigations and tests here are the results.

The share permission was **Modify**. Comparing with other shares on other servers where security permissions were inherited after file and folder move I put share permission to **Full**.

Now when my test user moves folders within the share from his client computer the security permissions of the destination folder are applied.